# How to set ItemsSource property programmatically?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

This is XAML code;

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="newTaskNameTextBox"
                         ItemsSource="{StaticResource BankNamesList}" />
```

How to assign this `ItemSource` attribute to the `newTaskNameTextBox` by C# programmatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(Solution for WPF)**

You should use the [TryFindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tryfindresource.aspx) method.

```
newTaskNameTextBox.ItemsSource = 
    (IEnumerable)newTaskNameTextBox.TryFindResource("BankNamesList");
```

This searches up the logical tree, in the same way `{StaticResource BankNamesList}` does.

---

**UPDATE: (solution for WP8)**

Sounds lile you're using **WP8** (which doesn't include `FindResource` / `TryFindResource`) so try this instead:

```
newTaskNameTextBox.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)Resources["BankNamesList"];
```

---

**UPDATE: (how to implement the missing TryFindResource)**

Note that the code above requires the resource to exist in the owner of this code behind (e.g. the window). However, there may be cases where the resource exists in another parent element up the logical tree. For example, you may be writing the code behind for a custom user control but the resource you're looking for exists in the MainWindow. For such cases, it wouldn't be too hard to write a basic implementation of WPF's `TryFindResouces`, which has the *advantage* of searching up the logical tree ([source link](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2011/01/findresource-implementation-for.html)):

```
public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
{
    public static object TryFindResource(this FrameworkElement element, object resourceKey)
    {
        var currentElement = element;

        while (currentElement != null)
        {
            var resource = currentElement.Resources[resourceKey];
            if (resource != null)
            {
                return resource;
            }

            currentElement = currentElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        }

        return Application.Current.Resources[resourceKey];
    }
}

/**********************************************************************/
// Or, the recursive version of TryFindResource method as suggested by @Default:

public static object TryFindResource(this FrameworkElement element, object resourceKey)
{
    if (element == null)
        return Application.Current.Resources[resourceKey];

    var resource = element.Resources[resourceKey];
    if (resource != null)
    {
        return resource;
    }
    return TryFindResource(element.Parent, resourceKey);
}
```

So if you include this `FrameworkElementExtensions` class in your namespace, then you should be able to do this (same code I've given for WPF originally):

```
newTaskNameTextBox.ItemsSource = 
    (IEnumerable)newTaskNameTextBox.TryFindResource("BankNamesList");
```

Comment: Error `'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.AutoCompleteBox' does not contain a definition for 'TryFindResource' and no extension method 'TryFindResource' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.AutoCompleteBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Csharp_Newbie try the edited code. Your question tags include both `wpf` and `windows-phone`, so you must be using `windows-phone`...

Comment: other users coming here might be looking for a WPF solution (even though that tag was removed now..). Would it be possible to keep that solution as well? I think that would benefit future visitors.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a recursive version of `TryFindResource` as a comment to your answer (so currently it isn't visible). To me it's shorter and less nesting but still easy to read. It wasn't valid as an answer to me, and to long to post as a comment. I hope you don't mind..

Answer (score 0):

If BankNamesList is resource in the resources of your window,  then in code behind you can do:

```
newTaskNameTextBox.ItemsSource = Resources["BankNamesList"]
```

Comment: Error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: typecaste the resource as (IEnumerable)Resources["BankNamesList"]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newTaskNameTextBox.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)(Application.Current.Resources["BankNamesList"]);
```

Comment: Error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`