# Why am I not able to use FindResource() in Windows phone programming?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to use `FindResource()` in C# Windows phone programming to change the style of a control, but I am not able to.

> `play_btn.Style = FindResource("btnplay") as Style;`

This gives an error: does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Where is `btnplay` Resource defined? and is it included in the correct place (like app.xaml / window.xaml)?

Comment: `btnply` is a style of button.i like change icon of this button in run time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your style is defined in `Resources` of the App.xaml, you have to use:

```
play_btn.Style = App.Current.Resources["btnplay"] as Style;
```

otherwise (e.g. MainPage.xaml, SecondPage.xaml ...):

```
play_btn.Style = this.Resources["btnplay"] as Style;
```

Or you can implement `TryFindResource` as extension method: "[How to implement the missing TryFindResource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18670481/1136101)".